# Render object as context in twig template

Tags: php, templates, twig

How to render an object instead of array, like we usually do?

```
echo $twig->render('index.html', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

The `render()` function does not accept an object.

Is there any way to render the object directly?.

And I do not mean an "objectToArray" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of the method render take an array for transport data to the view, so you simply put your object as value of the array with a specified key. Something like this:

```
$object = new People()
$object->setName('Fabien');
echo $twig->render('index.html', array('obj' => $object));
```

And use in the template as

```
{{ obj.name }}
```

Hope this help